# Search values of multiple keys with same name of items in array

Tags: javascript

I've an array like this:

```
const myArray = ['Item1', 'Item3', 'Item5'];
```

And an object list like that:

```
ObjectsList: {
    Item1: ["A", "B", "C"],
    Item2: ["A", "D", "E"],
    Item3: ["B", "E", "C", "G"],
    Item4: ["B", "C", "R"],
    Item5: ["D"],
    Item6: ["F", "D", "E"],
    Item7: ["A", "E", "L", "M"],
}
```

I want to get the values of all the keys with the same name of my array elements and push them into a new array without duplicate elements.

In the case of my provided example I want to get the Item1, Item3, Item5 keys values and push them in a new array avoiding duplicates. The result should be that: [A, B, C, E, G, D]

Which is the best way to do that in JavaScript?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [`.flatMap()`](https://www.google.com/search?q=mdn%20flatmap&oq=flatMap%20mdn&aqs=chrome.1.69i59j0l5.4246j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) your `myArray` to an array of characters from the `ObjectsList`, and then use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to remove the duplicate characters. Lastly, you can use the [spread syntax (`...`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to convert the set into an array:

```js
const objectsList = { Item1: ["A", "B", "C"], Item2: ["A", "D", "E"], Item3: ["B", "E", "C", "G"], Item4: ["B", "C", "R"], Item5: ["D"], Item6: ["F", "D", "E"], Item7: ["A", "E", "L", "M"], };
const myArray = ['Item1', 'Item3', 'Item5'];

const res = [...new Set(myArray.flatMap(k => objectsList[k]))];
console.log(res);
```

If you can't support `.flatMap()`, you can use a regular [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and then use [`.concat()`](https://www.google.com/search?q=concat%20mdn&oq=concat%20mdn&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0l7.1660j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) to perform the flattening:

```js
const objectsList = { Item1: ["A", "B", "C"], Item2: ["A", "D", "E"], Item3: ["B", "E", "C", "G"], Item4: ["B", "C", "R"], Item5: ["D"], Item6: ["F", "D", "E"], Item7: ["A", "E", "L", "M"], };
const myArray = ['Item1', 'Item3', 'Item5'];

const res = [...new Set([].concat(...myArray.map(k => objectsList[k])))];
console.log(res);
```